# MYSQL Insert Submit Button PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am generating a list of images and looking to insert a specific image based on wether or not a submit button has been pressed alongside my image.

Here is my code to generate a list of images. Alongside the images is the submit button, like count and other data:

```
// Display results
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
echo "<a href=\"{$data->link}\"</a>";
echo "<h4>Photo by: {$data->user->username}</h6>";
echo $pictureImage = "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\">";
echo "<h5>Like Count for Photo: {$data->likes->count}</h5>";
echo "<form>";
echo '<input type="submit" onClick=post()>';
echo "</form>";
}
```

I am then trying to insert that picture into my database:

**InstagramImages(DB) - image(field)**

```
function post() {

        $hostname = "redacted";
        $username = "redacted";
        $dbname = "redacted";

        //These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
        $password = "redacted";
        $usertable = "InstagramImages";

        //Connecting to your database
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname);

        $sql="INSERT INTO $usertable (image) VALUES ('$pictureImage')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        echo "1 record added";

        mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I need help creating the right INSERT query for the php variable $pictureImage.

Comment: um.. what's the problem or error your having exactly?

Comment: @JustAnil Sorry see edits.

Comment: as your html suggest generated by foreach loop, there will be multiple submit button with same name in a single page, having same function call post(); so you have to identify which submit button is pressed by passing some unique id parameter to that,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Always use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add values to your SQL queries, **never** use string interpolation without [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have nasty [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). It's unclear here why you're using `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_query` as the two are completely incompatible. You should be using `mysqli` or PDO, not `mysql_query` at all.

Answer (score 0):

also, `<form>` should be `<form method='post'>`

instead of `onclick = post()` change it to `name='post'`

and instead of `function post(){` make it `if($_POST['post']){`

Comment: Double quotes or single quotes for name='post'

Comment: @asg whichever, it technically doesnt matter. i prefer using single quotes in my html

Comment: I believe the problem now exists with my insert query. Any suggestions?

Comment: @asg this is going to be what developerCK said, you have many duplicates of the same form which is going to screw things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="submit" onClick=post()>';
```

**onClick=post()** - This is a javascript event used only for javascript but the post() function you have written in php code so it cannot insert into your tatabase table.